# Comparación en React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo que hacer una comparación de 2 hooks (código y código agregado), y la consola me muestra que ambos son iguales pero no entra a la comparación cuando son verdaderos, ya que no muestra la consola "llegó aquí"

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Desde ya muchas gracias.

```
    const RegistroNuevaCuenta = () => {
    
      const [codigo, setCodigo] = useState(0)
      const [codigo_agregado, setCodigo_agregado] = useState(1)

  
  const enviarRegistro =()=>{
     const completarRegistro =()=>{
    
        console.log(codigo);
        console.log(codigo_agregado);
    
        if(codigo===codigo_agregado){
    
          console.log("llego aquí")
          return (
            <BrowserRouter>
              <Switch>
                <Route path='http://127.0.0.1:8000/Completarinfo/' exact />
              </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
          );
          
        }
        else{
          setCount(6);
    
        }
      }
```

Comment: Va a depender de si los valores (`codigo` y `codigo_agregado`) son exactamente iguales tanto en valor como en tipo. Estás usando [comparación estricta](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Igualdad_Estricta_usando): `===`, tal vez los valores no sean del mismo tipo aunque tengan el mismo contenido. ¿Has probado usar la [comparación relajada](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Igualdad_d%C3%A9bil_usando): `==`? Prueba eso y comenta el resultado. Saludos

Comment: @Julian Por favor revisa el código que nos compartes, parece estar incompleto, hay dos funciones sin cierre definido, `registroNuevaCuenta` y `enviarRegistro`, tampoco se observa donde se llaman `enviarRegistro` y `completarRegistro`, saludos

Comment: Pero como va a entrar si 0 jamás sera igual a 1 =/

Comment: @g.4 Gracias, está incompleto debido a que solo copié una porción y me faltó en el copy-paste las llaves. El inconveniente ya fue solucionado debido a que los datos no son del mismo tipo y la comparación estricta no funcionaba.